# Is it possible to create a signal for when a QTreeWidgetItem checkbox is toggled?

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, signals-slots, qtreewidgetitem

I've created a checkbox that's also a QTreeWidgetItem using the code below.

```
//Populate list
QTreeWidgetItem *program = createCheckedTreeItem(QString::fromStdString(itr->first), true);
treePrograms->addTopLevelItem(program);
```

---

```
QTreeWidgetItem* ConfigDialog::createCheckedTreeItem(QString name,bool checkBoxState)
{
  QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList(name));
  item->setFlags(item->flags()|Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
  if (checkBoxState)
  {
    item->setCheckState(0,Qt::Unchecked);
  }
  else
  {
    item->setCheckState(0,Qt::Checked);
  }
  return item;
}
```

I need a way of connecting a signal and slot for when the state of this checkbox is changed. The current way I've implemented this is below but unfortunately doesn't work. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do in order to get it to connect?

```
connect(program, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(programChecked(bool)));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `QTreeWidgetItem` is directly linked to your model data, so you should connect to your QTreeWidget's model's `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged` signal to be notified of the change.

Comment: @GHuxley But you can still connect to a QTreeWidget's underlying default model, e.g. `treeWidget.model().dataChanged.connect(handle_dataChanged)`. Not sure if this is any better than just connecting to `itemChanged` but it seems similar.

Answer (score 8):

You have to grab the signal `itemChanged ( QTreeWidgetItem * item, int column )` coming from [QTreeWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html).

Comment: This is no good because it'll be signalled constantly as the tree data changes too.

Answer (score 6):

Connect to the signal `itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem* item, int column)` of the tree. When handling the signal, just verify `item->checkState(column)`.

Comment: When the user clicks on just the checkbox this will not the signaled. For instance, the user clicks the item. Then clicks the checkbox. The checkState will not be called on the checkbox click. This is true at least for Qt 5.3

Comment: I am using fine in Qt 5.3.1 at the moment, on both Mac and Win.

Comment: This works, but you have to check the item's checked state against your own model for changes.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution we found was to reimplement setData in an item subclass:

```
void MyItem::setData(int column, int role, const QVariant& value)
{
    const bool isCheckChange = column == 0
        && role == Qt::CheckStateRole
        && data(column, role).isValid() // Don't "change" during initialization
        && checkState(0) != value;
    QTreeWidgetItem::setData(column, role, value);
    if (isCheckChange) {
        MyTree *tree = static_cast<MyTree *>(treeWidget);
        emit tree->itemCheckStateChanged(this, checkState(0) == Qt::Checked);
    }
}
```

It would really be convenient to have this in Qt indeed, it makes me think about contributing a itemCheckStateChanged signal there directly :)

PS: setting Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable is unnecessary, this flag is on by default for all QTreeWidgetItems.

Answer (score 0):

Add this signal to your QTreeWidget object:

```
connect(ui->treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::itemChanged, this, &YourDialog::treeWidgetItemChanged);
```

so you can use this slot to receive the signal:

```
void YourDialog::treeWidgetItemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem *TWI, int column)
{
    //Do some staff
}
```